# Чи є українській відповідник до слова "мем"

Tags: переклад

Цікавить чи існує український відповідник до слова "Мем" (від англ. "meme") - явище спонтанного розповсюдження певної інформації інтернетом усіма можливими способами − електронною поштою, в месенджерах, форумах, блогах, тощо. На сторінці [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC#%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC) мені вдалося знайти сторінку, де є інформація про це слово, але немає жодного українського відповідника там. [Гугл перкладач](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#en/uk/meme) дає варіант "мем", а на сайті [Словотвору](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/mem) є такі варіанти як "мулька" та "посміхунок", але таких слів я не знайшов в СУМі.

Отож чи існує український відповідник до даного слова чи його можливо перекласти лише як "мем"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Як зазначає [Вікі](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%BC_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)), иншим перебуквуванням для [*meme*](//dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/meme) є ***мім***, що доречніше:

- за звучнею [/miːm/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme);
- через [ікавізм](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4_[%C4%9B]_%D0%B2_[%D1%96]), до того ж з [власним](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) жартівливим відтіном; звісно, голосна не чергуватиметься чи викидатиметься, оскільки чужоземне походження;
- за повною назвою *мімема* і [словопоходженням](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme#Etymology): з давньогрецького слова ***μίμ**[ημα](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F)* /míːmɛːma/ “imitated thing” ⟶ *μιμεῖσθαι* “to imitate” ⟶ *μῖμος* “mime“; й відси знов звучнею, а також вже існуючими словами з [цим](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BC) словопохідним корнем: [*мім*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=51482), *мімік*, *міміка*, *міміст*, *мімічний*…

Коли брати суто український відповідник, то за [словником Павла Штепи](//storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1320) можна від *міміка* отримати непогане за означенням від СУМ і навіть трохи подібним звучанням слово *миги*, котре тут, правда, має лиш число множини. Але, инші словники вказують, що існує й однина [***мига***](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0&dicts=all&highlight=on), також зустрічається як [***миґа***](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D2%91%D0%B0&highlight=on).

> [**Миги**, ів](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50967), *мн.*, *розм.* Знаки (підморгування, жести), які супроводжують, а часто й заступають розмову.
>    *В мигах, в розмові венгрів [угорців] було видко щось східне* (І. Нечуй-Левицький);
>    *Йому бракувало іноді потрібних слів, тоді він допомагав собі мигами й усякими вихилясами* (Б. Антоненко-Давидович).
>
> [Порозуміва́тися (порозумі́тися) на ми́гах](http://sum.in.ua/s/porozumivatysja) — вести розмову, спілкуватися за допомогою жестів, знаків і т. ін.
>    *Рабиням і служникам не дозволено розмовляти в присутності падишаха.. Навіть сам на сам порозуміваються вони в палаці на мигах, наче глухонімі* (Зінаїда Тулуб, Людолови, II, 1957, 340);
>    *Охорона маєтку найбільш ускладнювала справу.. — Мови не розуміють.. — Проте, може б, хоч на мигах якось порозумілися, та стражник, що до них приставлений, і близько не підпускає до них* (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 260);
>
> ○ **На ми́гах**, *у знач. присл., зі сл.* **говорити**, **розмовляти**, **пояснювати**, **показувати** і т. ін. — за допомогою жестів, міміки і т. ін.
>    *Дівчата щось поясняли старій на мигах, .. але все надаремне: стара не розуміла* (М. Коцюбинський); *Золотаренко показав писареві на мигах, що не треба турбувати гетьмана* (П. Панч);
>    *Михайло порушує порядок, він підійшов і на мигах попросив загасити свічу і лягати...* (Б. Левін);
>    *Щось на мигах пояснюючи Катеринi, Омелян видобув зi спiдньої кишенi конверт* (Р. Андріяшик).

---

Коли випадково знайшов неочікуване для мене написання однини з закінченням *а*, а також з *ґ*, то рішив [перевірити](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=457) походження. Слово походить від польського (вже чоловічого роду) *[mig](http://wsjp.pl/index.php?id_hasla=41281&id_znaczenia=4874380&l=15&ind=0)i*, що від псл. *migati* — відки й українське [*мигати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/myghaty) і подальні однопневі. Сильних втрат означень не відбулося і залишається українським відповідником. Чисто уявно, теж можна вживати існуючого чоловічого [***миг***](http://sum.in.ua/s/mygh), для котрого множина теж [*миги*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3). Також цікавим є рішення Павла Штепи вказати *мита*, що, схоже, походить від *мить*, для *жест*.

Comment: _перебукваванням_, _звучнею_ - серйозно?

Comment: Я так розумію, що *мім* це одиниця інформації, що здатна відтворювати себе. Не бачу зв'язку з *мигами*.

Comment: @Yola Почнїмо з того, що навів приклад словника, ось тут вже звʼязок, далї вказав, що схоже за означенням (_знак_, як одиниця чогось), котрих навів. Як бачно, теж здатні відтворювати себе (_заступають_). Коли одволікло, то: 1) _мім_ не постійна річ; 2) вже існують дїєслова з цӧго корня, котрі _передають_ відомости (переважно очима): _мигати_ блимати, _умигнути_ відвести, _мигну́ти_ майнути, ударити, _мигатися_ виднітися (маяк)…

Comment: Якщо правильніше казати мім а не мем, то чому ми кажемо ген а не гін?

Comment: @Bunyk бо _ген_ вôд _γένος_?

Comment: А мем від "ген". Цитуючи винахідника цього слова: "Ми потребували назву для нового реплікатора, іменника який би висловлював ідею одиниці культурної передачі або одиниці "наслідування" . 'Mimeme' ('наслідувати') походить від придатного грецького кореня, але я хотів односкладове слово, яке звучить подібно 'ген'. Я сподіваюсь мої друзі-класики пробачать мені скорочення mimeme до meme. Якщо це когось втішить, можна альтернативно думати, що воно пов'язане з 'memory' (пам'ять) чи з французьким словом même. Воно буде вимовлятися в риму з 'cream' (крем, вимовляється - крІм). "

Comment: Коротше кажучи ця відповідь базується на помилкових припущеннях, бо мем - це мімема, але скорочене не до мім, а до "мема".

Comment: @Bunyk Шчо ж, зме̂на _е → і_ не ускладнює слово, воно досье̂ залишає ся однокороневим. Як розуме̂ю, винахо̂дник слова — Анґлянӗць, тому буде [miːm] проти [dʒiːn], одна голосна збе̂гає ся, а _m_ та _n_ однаково носове̂, приклад [kɹiːm] лише по̂дтвердює напрям. Тому _мем ↔ ґен_ має якогось смисла. Гадаю, можете додати тут ланку на џерело його витяга, тодо̂ додам собе̂ з вашим перекладом або можете во̂дпове̂сти саме̂.

Answer (score 6):

В СУМ-20 присутнє слово ***"мем"***, тому сміливо можемо його використовувати.

> ***[Мем](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=203286&page=1599)***, а, ч. Одиниця культурної інформації, поширювана від однієї людини до іншої за допомогою мовлення, письма, відео, ритуалів,
> жестів і т. ін. *Мем – це ідея, символ, манера чи спосіб дії, що
> свідомо чи несвідомо передаються від людини до людини* (з наук.-попул.
> літ.); *Уся культурна інформація складається з базових одиниць – мемів,
> так само як біологічна інформація складається з генів* (з навч. літ.).

На мою думку, краще використовувати саме слово ***"мем"***, не замінювати на якісь інші.